# AS3 Child error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, removechild, addchild

as you are about to be I am fairly new to coding as3... I always get these kinds of errors when I try to remove children...
Im not using classes right now, just using the Include method.
TypeError: Error #1006: removeChild is not a function.
can anyone explain to me how to use this correctly? if that is not a such a broad question.

```
var children = 0;

function pineClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
var chopBtn:MovieClip = new MenuItem  ;
var shakeBtn:MovieClip = new MenuItem  ;
var pineCancelBtn:MovieClip = new MenuItem  ;


if (chopMode == false && children <1) {
    children++;
    addChild(chopBtn);
    chopBtn.x = 250;
    chopBtn.y = 140;
    chopBtn.MenuItemText.text = "Chop";
    addChild(shakeBtn);
    shakeBtn.x = 250;
    shakeBtn.y = 200;
    shakeBtn.MenuItemText.text = "Shake";
    addChild(pineCancelBtn);
    pineCancelBtn.x = 250;
    pineCancelBtn.y = 260;
    pineCancelBtn.MenuItemText.text = "Cancel";
    pineCancelBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pineCancelClick);
    chopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pineChopClick);


    function pineChopClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

        var length:uint = inventoryItems.length;
        for (var i:uint= 0; i<length; i++) {
            if (inventoryItems[i] == "Hatchet") {
                itemEquipped = true;
            }
            if (itemEquipped == true) {
                chopMode = true;
                removeChild(shakeBtn);        /////error here//////
                removeChild(pineCancelBtn);   /////////////////////
                removeChild(chopBtn);         /////////////////////
            } else {
                itemEquipped = false;
            }
        }
        if (itemEquipped == false) {
            Output.text = insertTextBefore("You need a Hatchet to cut this.");
        }
    }



    function pineCancelClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        chopMode = false;
        removeChild(chopBtn);
        removeChild(shakeBtn);
        removeChild(pineCancelBtn);
        children = 0;
    }
}
if (chopMode == true) {
    removeChild(chopBtn);
    removeChild(shakeBtn);
}
}
```

Comment: do a trace for `shakeBtn` before you remove it. Do you get something that isn't `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a direct problem of scope. Because you nested functions the inner function has lost scope.

This is exactly why we never ever ever nest functions.

If you un-nest your functions your problem will go away


Or you could try this.

```
MovieClip(root).removeChild(XXXXX)
```

Comment: I'm curious about this. Since the Children he's trying to remove are declared at the top of his code, how could they be 'out of scope' in a deeply nested function? thanks, c.u.

Comment: @Craig The children are declared inside of the pineClick function. and as such the reference to those objects (IE: chopBtn, shakeBtn, pineCancelBtn) will only be accessible from inside that function. So what you are thinking is the function pineChopClick is also declared inside and that should be able to reference those variables also, but it does. That function is called on a click event which will be long after the outer function has run and been garbage collected. Hope this helps you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky but this should do the trick

```
if(shakeBtn.parent != null)
    shakeBtn.parent.removeChild(shakeBtn);
```

Comment: this worked thanks! my coding skills are not that great yet.  I should probably learn more about containers.

Comment: This works, but you should really be working with classes if you want to make anything more complicated.
Why it didn't work was because it was probably already removed from somewhere, and you cant removeChild() that isn't inside of parent from which you are removing.
Maybe you just want to have a single function RemoveButtons() for example, so you don't have to have same piece of code at 3 different places and when you need to remove it just call that function.